# SilverStripe layout and templates

Tags: silverstripe

Given the code below

Test.ss (in Templates)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    Templates
    $Layout
</body>
</html>
```

---

Test.ss (in Layout)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Layout</title>
</head>
<body>
    Layout
</body>
</html>
```

Output in SilverStripe:

Templates
Layout

My question is is SilverStripe stripping html tags in layout?

Comment: In your case Layout/Test.ss is not used at all. Please read documentation first. http://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/working-with-multiple-templates

Comment: I tested your code and all that I got was `Templates`. This is correct as `templates/Layout/Test.ss` doesn't get loaded because there is no `$Layout` in your `templates/Test.ss` file. I don't understand how you are getting a result of `Templates Layout`.

Comment: It was a typo I have a $Layout in templates/Test.ss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SilverStripe does not strip out html tags from your layout templates. The html you have in your template will be printed as is.

So your example templates will result in the following html output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    Templates
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Layout</title>
</head>
<body>
    Layout
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

You can view this for yourself by viewing your page source. In chrome the URL would be `view-source:http://your-website-url`

Avoid having `html`, `head` and `body` tags in `layout` templates as this is taken care of in the main template.

Instead, your `template/layouts/test.ss` file should look like this:

```
    <p>Layout</p>
```

With your original `template/test.ss` this would give you an output of:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    Templates
    <p>Layout</p>
</body>
</html>
```